# How do you remove standalone alphabets from a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am currently working with lyric data of several artists.
When I was working with BTS lyric data, I noticed that the data had names of the member who sang that line at the front as you can see in the example below.

```
    Artist       Lyric
bts(방탄소년단)  jungkook 'cause i i i'm in the stars tonight s...
bts(방탄소년단)  방탄소년단의 fake love 가사 v jungkook 널 위해서라면 난 슬퍼도...
```

I tried removing their names with the str.replace() method.
However, one of their name seems to be "v" and when I try to remove "v" it removes all v's from the column as demonstrated below

```
    Artist       Lyric
bts(방탄소년단)  'cause i i i'm in the stars tonight s...
bts(방탄소년단)   방탄소년단의 fake lo e 가사  널 위해서라면 난 슬퍼도...
```

It would be really appreciated if there would be any way to remove a "v" that stands alone, but maintain the v's that are actually inside a word such as the v in love.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you post here what you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all single letters in you data, let's say that you have the following dataframe

```
   artist              lyrics
0  sdsddssd  fdgdg v sdsssdvsdd
1  sffxxvxv        sddsdsdvdfdf
2   vxvxvxv     fdagsgvs  v v v
3     zcczc           xdfsddfds
4     zcczc         vxvxdfdvdvd
```

then

```
dg['lyrics'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(word for word in x.split() if len(word)>1))
```

returns:

```
0    fdgdg sdsssdvsdd
1        sddsdsdvdfdf
2            fdagsgvs
3           xdfsddfds
4         vxvxdfdvdvd
Name: lyrics, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was very intuitive!!

Comment: If it was the answer you were looking for, do Mark it as accepted so it doesn't remain an unanswered question.